# What exactly does 门风帮闲 mean?

Tags: word

The follow is an except from 《水浒传》 第二回. Based on 端王's personality traits, he could have been a Shakespeare or, at least, a Balzac, or, perhaps, under favourable circumstances, a Galileo.

I wonder what exactly 门风 in 门风帮闲 means.

> 这端王乃是神宗天子第十一子，哲宗皇帝御弟，现掌东驾，排号九大王，是个聪明
>   俊俏人物。这浮浪子弟门风帮闲之事，无一般不晓，无一般不会，更无一般不爱。
>   即如琴、棋、书、画，无所不通，踢毬打弹，品竹调丝，吹弹歌舞，自不必说。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`门风`: `family customary moral standards and way of life`.

`浮浪子弟`: `vagrant or unemployed persons`, usually used for the people without a real job, just dawdling/playing everday.

So `浮浪子弟门风` refers to a life style, just screwing around, never get down to business.

`帮闲`, according to [here](http://club.kdnet.net/dispbbs.asp?id=9139282&boardid=1), `帮闲者，替别人帮着打发百无聊赖的休闲时光`. `帮` is `help`, `闲` is `leisure`, so `帮闲` means `help someone to kill/waste time`, here it means `keep company with someone to dawdle and play`.

Answer (score 2):

门风，门派的风气。
The rule of certain 帮派（gang，gaction）

Comment: Thanks, @Ping Tang. Somehow my gut feeling says it's a verb.

Comment: Nope，similary，帮闲means帮派的闲事、杂事。Are you studying Chinese？We can help each other.I am studying Eng..

Comment: OK. That make sense. So both are nouns. I'm a native Chinese speaker too. In English, you find a master piece and learn it by heart, then your writing skill magically improves. I'm trying to the same thing with  Chinese master pieces.